# Sharepoint Designer Workflow Email after Pause Until

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying to create simple workflow which will send an email on a particular day. I'm running into a problem each time I try to use  `pause for duration action`, or `pause until action`.

Each time I try to use send mail action after pause action I get error in my workflow history:

```
The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly
```

My mail action works perfectly when used without pause action or used before the Pause action.

For example:

if I use statement after pause action

```
Pause until 'Date'

then Send Mail

Log Mail has been sent
```

In this case, the whole workflow gets executed but mail is not sent and the log file is also executed. I get  `The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly`

However, if I take out action "`Pause until` " from the above statement, mail gets sent without any problems.

Tried out many options suggested in different link none looks working out but my mail reminders work fine outside pause action.

not much help from ULS logs also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to the fact that the workflow will run in a different context when such a delay action is used.

Make sure the sharepoint timerjob that for workflows (which is used to send the email in that case) uses an account that has permissions to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Wait for field to equal value` clause.  It seems you already have a Date column.  You could set up a `Date and Time` column called `Today` with a default value of `Today's Date`.  Then include the clause `Wait for Date to equal Today`.